# How do I set up a named route in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, custom-routes

This is a month long thing I've been putting off, and I can't for the life of me figure this bugger out.

I'm tracking to access a file in `website/admin/organizations/org_deals`

My routes look like this :

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.namespace :organizations do |organization|
    organization.org_deals 'org_deals', :action => 'org_deals'
  end
end
```

rake routes | grep org_deals :

```
admin_organizations_org_deals   /admin/organizations/org_deals    {:controller=>"admin/organizations/", :action=>"org_deals"}
```

I made my link look like this

```
admin_organizations_org_deals_path
```

I mouse over the link I get `http://localhost:3000/admin/organizations/org_deals`

I click on it, and I get :

```
No such file or directory - /Users/daniellevine/Sites/hq_channel/app/views/admin/organizations/show.html.haml
```

WTF? :D

Comment: Looks to me like the route is working fine. Does your view exist where it's looking for it?

Comment: Yes its definately in there. But see how its looking for a show? If I rename my view to show.haml.html, it's good to go which is what I've been doing. I wonder if there's some sort of contradicting route that's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with routes just a few days ago when i upgraded to rails 3, i can't tell you bout namespaces cuz i didn't used it yet, but this guide was very helpful to me, there's a topic on namespaces, hope it helps: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html